# Log4net doesn't write to file during MSBuild

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, log4net, xunit

What I want to do is to log some events from xunit test with log4net.

Everything works fine when I run test manually from Visual Studio, but when I run them in MSBuild, nothing is logged. I have already checked if the config file for test.dll is missing, but that was not the case. What else could be the reason for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can check:

- is your log4net.config file copied to the directory where the tests are executed
- is the filename where you try to log relative to the path you are running msbuild? And do you have access to that file? Make it an absolute path to be sure.
- is the a configure attribute in the dll you try to test? Point it to the right configutation file